# Bug in C++ Set?

Tags: c++, set, stdset

When I tried this part of the code:

```
int x=*(s.rbegin());
while(!s.empty()&&0<x)
{
    s.erase(x);
    x=*(s.rbegin());
}
```

It runs into an infinite loop because it doesn't actually erase anything when I call erase. This seems weird because *(s.rbegin()) should definitely be in s.

Comment: What's the value of x?

Comment: You have undefined behavior after the last value of the set is erased, and then you dereference an iterator from it. Unless you can guarantee that the `0<x` condition will be broken before the set is empty.

Comment: How did you declare `s`?

Comment: That's std::set<int> x? Or some other set?

Comment: What Benjamin Lindley said; segfaults for me on last item (but doesn't go in infinite loop.   You're going to need to provide a bit more details on your c++ version and the rest of your code (e.g. what is s containing? )

Comment: When `erase()` is used to remove the last element in the set (after which the set is empty), `s.rbegin()` will be equal to `s.rend()`, and evaluating `x` then gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Change order of actions, you delete element  you wanted to get.. for example:

```
 std::set<int> s;

 int x;
 s.insert(5);
 s.insert(15);
 s.insert(25);
 s.insert(0);
 s.insert(20);
 while(!s.empty()&& (0<(x=*s.rbegin())))
 {
     std::cout<< x << "\n";
     s.erase(x);
 }
```

Be aware that in way you defined while. Output of code above will be

```
25
20
15
5
```

Be aware that in way you defined while() loop you intended to stop if it finds 0 element. There is 0 left after the exit, set will not be empty. Traditionally used iteration looks like

```
for (auto it=s.rbegin(); it!=s.rend(); ++it)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if (!s.empty())
{
    int x = *(s.rbegin());
    while (0 < x)
    {
        s.erase(x);
        if (s.empty()) break;
        x = *(s.rbegin());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, try erasing using iterators instead of values:

```
std::set<int>::reverse_iterator iter = s.rbegin();
while ((iter != s.rend()) && ((0 < *iter))
    s.erase((iter++).base());
```

Comment: std::remove_if will not work with std::set,  you'll get assignment of read-only location error. last compiler that could do that of which I know was vc6 (due to some unusual implementations of STL)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to erase all elements in the set which are positive. This can be done much simpler with this single line:

```
s.erase(s.upper_bound(0),s.end());
```

`upper_bound` gives you the iterator to the first number greater than 0. Since all elements from this one to the end are guaranteed to be greater than zero, you can erase them all.

Answer (score -1):

You should check for the end of set before `x=*(s.rbegin());`

```
int x=*(s.rbegin());
while(!s.empty() && 0<x)
{
    s.erase(x);
    if(!s.empty())
        x=*(s.rbegin());
}
```

Comment: "*check for the end of set*" - that applies to the first `rbegin()` as well before entering the loop, not just the `rbegin()` inside the loop.